# How often should we expect 400 Bad Request?

Tags: http, apache-2.2, 400, bad-request

We run an Apache2 web server which has somewhere in the vicinity of 2-3 million pages served every day (only HTML+CSS+Javascript, images and other content is served with Lighttpd). Our daily `logwatch` e-mail outputs somewhere between 3-5 "400 Bad Request" items a day. It is mostly for the same URLs every day, but rarely more than 1 time per URL. The URLs listed are mostly for standard page views on our website (URLs that almost every user will visit).

When grepping the `error.log` for the IPs listed in the `access.log` as having received the error, the result is always `[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] request failed: error reading the headers, referer: xxx`.

My assumption is that these are nothing to worry about, at least when they are this infrequent.

Is the number of errors we are seeing here produced by dropped connections, or something similar? What should I examine to figure it out? Should I just leave it alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you are seeing, if the same IPs logging the errors can later successfully access the site, then it is probably very safe to ignore the infrequent errors for the rational that you have presented.

Comment: Yes, they can. Grepping for the IP in `access.log` for all of the IPs I've inspected reveals that the bad request is just one many requests.

Comment: Then you should be fine in ignoring the errors.

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on MrTuttle's answer, the 400 errors I've investigated in the wild are typically someone trying (unsuccessfully) to exploit your webserver, typically because they haven't noticed that you're not running a vulnerable version, or they just don't care.  A fair proportion of the 404 errors I get on my sites are in the same boat -- attempts to exploit vulnerable webapps I don't have installed (phpmyadmin, I'm glaring at you).

Comment: These are usually the w00tw00t-requests, which I am aware of. I keep my server patched, and also review the SSH logs with logwatch... :)

Comment: A very good point! And if I had 1/15th of a cent for every time someone scanned my servers for phpmyadmin....

Answer (score 2):

Kudos for actually reviewing your logs! I'd ignore the 400 errors. 99.999% of the time, they're client-side, and completely outside your purview; network flakeyness or a spyware-ridden browser, in my experience.